# Jquery datatable object doesnt support this method or property 'row'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I've seen this question around but havent seen an answer that is applicable to my particular case.

This doesnt appear to be the scoping issue that most people run into as I can see datatable assigned to its var and look at its properties in the debugger.

This is MVC4 using razor code

The error occurs here  var rowinfo = oTable.row(tr);

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function () {

        var oTable = $("#mainTable").dataTable();

        $("#mainTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
            debugger;
            var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
               var rowinfo = oTable.row(tr);

            alert(rowinfo);

        });

    });
```

this is pretty much the basic example code from the datatables page.
the full html page is

```
 @model StaticAnalysis.Models.FindDriverModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Find a Driver";
}

<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $("#mainTable").dataTable();

        $("#mainTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
            debugger;
            var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var rowinfo = oTable.row(tr);

            alert(rowinfo);

        });

        });

</script>

<h3>Find a driver</h3>

<section id="finddriver">
@using (Html.BeginForm("FindDriver", "DcbitSql", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.searchfor)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchfor)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </fieldset>
}
</section>
    <hr/>

<div class="FindDriverResult">

@if(Model.searchfor != null)
{
        <b><text>Results for @Model.searchfor</text></b>
    <table id="mainTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Mfg</th>
                <th>FileVersion</th>
                <th>Checksum</th>
                <th>TimeStamp</th>
                <th>Arch</th>
                @*<th>FilePath</th>*@

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.dtDetailList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action( "FindDriverApisPartial", new { time = 

item.timestamp,name = item.Name })"  target="target">@item.Name</a></td>
                       @* <td>@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name,  
 "FindDriverApisPartial",      { id = item.timestamp }, new object { target = 
"apipartial" }) </td>*@


                   <td>@item.Mfg</td>
                    <td>@item.FileVersion</td>
                    <td>@item.Checksum</td>
                    <td>@item.timestamp</td>
                    <td>@item.Arch</td>
                   @* <td>@item.Path</td>*@
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
</div>
    <div id="target">
</div>
```

and the jquery \ css \ datatable code is loaded from a common layout page _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Static Driver Analysis</title>


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTables")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@
@* @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</head>

... //more html common layout bleh
```

What Im trying to accomplish in the end is being able to select a row in the datatable grab some of the column values then make a call to the controller to do a new sql query and load the results as a partial page which contains a new datatable with the additional info.

Thanks in advance!

As far as what version of dataTables I'm using here is the Code from RegisterBundles. I've tried using the local copy and downloading 1.10.3 in release mode.

```
     public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        var dtableCdnPath = "http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3   
/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js";

        bundles.UseCdn = true;

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
                //    "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.2/jquery.dataTables.js"));
               //    ""));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dataTables",dtableCdnPath).Include(
                  "~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.2/jquery.dataTables.js"));
```

I've also fooled with changing the load order to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: What version of datatables are you using?

Comment: I tried DataTables-1.10.2 and 1.10.3

Comment: try this : `var row = oTable.api().row(tr);`

Comment: Try `var rowInfo = oTable.row(tr[0]);` The jquery object you are passing might not be accepted by dataTables.

Comment: @charlietfl You Rock!!  I had seen a previous post where the original poster had stated this was the solution but as a property not a method. (i.e. var row = oTable.api.row(tr);  ) needless to say that did not work !!

Comment: interesting that the .row method does not work as is. I've seen js fiddles where it performs as expected